# What is the best practice to implement user review stars in Android?

Tags: android

What I want to implement is product review stars. I have a score (between 0 and 5) for each product. I want to represent it on 5 stars. For example, if the score is 2.3, first two stars and 30% of the third star will be colored. It seems like a typical task. What's the good practice for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest, if you're only doing to .1 precision, just having 10 different images for stars (.1 - 1.0). Aesthetically, you might not want to be that precise without a numeric display.

Also, your question is very broad, could you focus on what exactly you need help with?

If you're looking for a library, you might try [AndroidViews](http://www.androidviews.net/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. That works, but do you think there's a easier way to do this?

Comment: @FeiQu If you are not going to use a library, then no.

Comment: Ha i c. What about library? Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android widget [RatingBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think RatingBar is for getting input. What I want is just showing users product reviews.